# Magento Custom Modules disable cannot show default information

Tags: magento-1.7

I have create a new magento website and only installed one plugin.
`Magemaven_ordercomment`

It is working in `sales/order` page, it is showing the order information with order comment.

However, when I disable the modules in system configuration, and go to  `sales/order` page,
the page cannot display any information, it cannot show the grid.

I know when I change the coding on `etc/modules` to false can show back the default information
But this method is not the good way to manage the system
Would it have any other method to fix it?

---

When enable the modules:
it added a columns for showing comment

### https://www.dropbox.com/s/zepgzwlvi4ap8jl/Screenshot%202014-04-11%2014.15.57.png

When disable the modules: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/btmcy8mb5c1e0az/Screenshot%202014-04-11%2014.15.19.png

---

class Magemaven_OrderComment_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{
    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
     protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'ordercomment/order_grid_collection';
    }

```
/**
 * Prepare grid columns
 *
 * @return Magemaven_OrderComment_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    // Add order comment to grid
    $this->addColumn('ordercomment', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('ordercomment')->__('Order Comment'),
        'index' => 'ordercomment',
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

}

when i disable the modules, the page cannot show the grid because  parent::_prepareColumns(); cannot run ?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you disable the extension in admin panel what will happen is, still the code in extension will run but it won't show the output.
2. But when you mark it as false in the app/etc/modules/ activation file, Magento will not execute the extension code. So if you don't want to use the extension this is the suitable way. The disabling module( first method) will just hide the out put of it.